# extract text between two words in php

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I got the following URL

```
http://www.amazon.com/LEGO-Ultimate-Building-Set-Pieces/dp/B000NO9GT4/ref=sr_1_1?m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&s=toys-and-games&ie=UTF8&qid=1350518571&sr=1-1&keywords=lego
```

and I want to extract

```
B000NO9GT4
```

that is the asin...to now, I can get search between the string, but not in this way I require. I saw the split functin, I saw the explode. but cant find a way out...also, the urls will be different in length so I cant hardcode the length two..the only thing which make some sense in my mind is to split the string so that

```
http://www.amazon.com/LEGO-Ultimate-Building-Set-Pieces/dp/
```

become first part

and

```
B000NO9GT4/ref=sr_1_1?m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&s=toys-and-games&ie=UTF8&qid=1350518571&sr=1-1&keywords=lego
```

becomes the 2nd part , from the second part , I should extract  `B000NO9GT4`

in the same way, i would want to get product name `LEGO-Ultimate-Building-Set-Pieces` from the first part

I am very bad at regex and cant find a way out..

can somebody guide me how I can do it in php?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This grabs both pieces of information that you are looking to capture:

```
$url = 'http://www.amazon.com/LEGO-Ultimate-Building-Set-Pieces/dp/B000NO9GT4/ref=sr_1_1?m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&s=toys-and-games&ie=UTF8&qid=1350518571&sr=1-1&keywords=lego';

$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

if (preg_match('#^/([^/]+)/dp/([^/]+)/#i', $path, $matches)) {
    echo "Description = {$matches[1]}<br />"
        ."ASIN = {$matches[2]}<br />";
}
```

Output:

> Description = LEGO-Ultimate-Building-Set-Pieces
>   ASIN = B000NO9GT4

Short Explanation:

- Any expressions enclosed in `( )` will be saved as a capture group.  This is how we get at the data in `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`.
- The expression `([^/]+)` says to match all characters EXCEPT `/` so in effect it captures everything in the URL between the two `/` separators.  I use this pattern twice.  The `[ ]` actually defines the character class which was `/`, the `^` in this case negates it so instead of matching `/` it matches everything BUT `/`.  Another example is `[a-f0-9]` which would say to match the characters `a,b,c,d,e,f` and the numbers `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.  `[^a-f0-9]` would be the opposite.
- `#` is used as the delimiter for the expression
- `^` following the delimiter means match from the beginning of the string.

See [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and [PCRE Pattern Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) for more info on how regexps work.

Comment: although I got what I want, but can you please explain this regex part '#^/([^/]+)/dp/([^/]+)/#i'

Comment: or please refer to me an easy tutorial for regex..whenever I try to learn regex, I run away seeing the ugly symbols...and regex is quite a nightmare for me

Comment: the links and the explanation is the real help...I owe you @drew010 for this guideline

Comment: :) thanks , I just edited the answer to expand a little more on a couple of points so make sure to read the explanation again.

Comment: thanks again bro....that is really really helpful in understanding the answer..would that i could vote up for more then one time..Thumbs up bro..thanks for help..specially for this very short and effective tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$str = "http://www.amazon.com/LEGO-Ultimate-Building-Set-Pieces/dp/B000NO9GT4/ref=sr_1_1?m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&s=toys-and-games&ie=UTF8&qid=1350518571&sr=1-1&keywords=lego" ;
list(,$desc,,$num,) = explode("/",parse_url($str,PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump($desc,$num);
```

Output

```
string 'LEGO-Ultimate-Building-Set-Pieces' (length=33)
string 'B000NO9GT4' (length=10)
```